# Problem with an AJAX Example on W3schools

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

[Link to example.](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first)

I replaced the URL 'ajax_info.txt' by a website URL (http://...) which responds with some text. The resulting code works in IE 8.

1. Why is the code not working for Chrome (no responseText)?
2. What is the solution (without using any library)?

Thank you for your time.

*P.S:* I am very new to web development.

Comment: its better you go for jquery because its make you development faster and easy to understand

Comment: also, try to avoid believing anything w3schools says: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: First great bit of advice: *Don't use W3Schools to learn*. Use [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Answer (score 2):

Browsers have a security limitation called 'same origin policy.' It prevents random websites from making requests on your behalf using your identity information stored in the browser via cookies or localStorage. For example if w3schools.com could make an AJAX request to facebook.com it could find out where you lived or who your friends are if you have that information on Facebook. Browsers prevent this kind of a request by only allowing AJAX requests to make requests to the domain, port and protocol (http or https for example) that the document originated from.

More information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

This is why your request did not work in Chrome, assuming you put some random site's URL in place of the text file. I am not sure why it would have worked for IE 8. I doubt it would.

Comment: Thank you. The w3schools code does work in IE 8. The 'expected' responseText is returned by the URL. What options do I have sans using a library?

Answer (score 0):

If you new and you want to avoid most of cross javascripting issues go for [jQquery](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://jquery.com/&rct=j&q=jquery&ei=vzOITZT3GIa6sQOw36mgDA&usg=AFQjCNFA7CZ5sWRDhHPuipmhL7zVksjC2A&sig2=ngtsuD91VOgtXl7y5oNtjA&cad=rja)

which lightweight and have less problems when there is no of browser involved

for you current issue you can go for jQuery .[Ajax()](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/&rct=j&q=jquery%20+%20ajax&ei=3jOITdvUJpSasAO86pSNDA&usg=AFQjCNF1ITsE5bJBc65MY4nqhZq7OkHZpg&sig2=6zJVtgGR6Ijs_rGb-kM7Dg&cad=rja) method will resolve your issue

Comment: @Pranay Rana, Thank you. I will start learning jQuery. So there is no solution without using jQuery?

Comment: I do not believe jQuery is good for beginners if the beginner is serious about learning JavaScript. jQuery is good for people who do not want to learn how to properly use JavaScript or people who already know JavaScript. I do not think it is wise to push new developers to jQuery.

Comment: @Meow - there is but I would like you to go for jQuery rather than pure javascript becuase there are jQuery make the code small and easy to understand .... It better than you learn basic of Javascript and than go for jQuery so you can get idea why to go for jQuery for development rather than pure javascript

Comment: @apphacker not true. jquery is totally for all levels. it abstracts a lot of the BS out of Javascript and makes it very user friendly for the novice as well as taking care of a LOT of cross browser issues. if you learn jquery first you have no choice but to learn more about javascript if you want to do more things.

Comment: @Pranay Rana, @apphacker - So, any workaround for Chrome without using any library?

Comment: @Jason I love jQuery as much as the next developer. It is a great library, but it is definitely not for new people. The misuse of 'this' and lack of learning about proper event handling or how that works, etc. They're going to have to 'unlearn' things if they start with jQuery. Not a good thing.

Comment: @apphacker - i learned javascript by way of jQuery a few years ago and it is the only reason why i decided i was confident enough to learn actual javascript. it is a fantastic tool for beginners and even better for those who don't want to spend the time learning the nuances and oddities of javascript but want to get some basic javascript effects on their page. sure the purists will say "oh but you don't know actual javascript." ok, yeah but have fun writing your own cross-browser XMLHttpRequest obj while I use `$.ajax()` and move on with my project.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery will make you code much easier to manage so go for it. If you really don't want to use library have a look on this [www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequeste](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)

Then about the code in the link you provided. I'm able to execute it without any error in chrome. Do the ajax request in your chrome browser did not encounter any error. Try to use the [chrome developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html), here you will see the response status sent by the server. Also you can see if there's an error on your js code.

Comment: I do not get an error as such. When I try displaying the responseText in Chrome (using innerHTML), it doesn't work (nothing happens). In IE 8, the responseText from XHR is displayed perfectly. I'm using the exact code and URL for both the browsers. I am stumped.

Comment: Did you try to use the chrome developer tools? also try to put the response in alert. It is better if you will know how to use the tools in chrome. In its Network tab you will see the response whether it has a value or just receive a status like 200. To open it. click the tools on upper right corner of your browser then goto Tools and click  Developer Tools.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I figured out the main issue: In Chrome, xhr.status != 200, whereas in IE 8, it is. Also, xhr.readyState = 4 in both the browsers (as expected). Any solution to this?

Comment: if it is !=200 what it is? Did you ever try it in Firefox if not run it and see if same error may occurr. Also as you see from the post the don't advice to learn w3Schools. Better find another tutorial sites. And try to study JQuery as the majority of the poster post. See this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

```
(function(c, I, B) {
        c.fn.responsiveSlides = function(l) {
                var a = c.extend({
                    auto: !0,
                    speed: 500,
                    timeout: 4E3,
                    pager: !1,
                    nav: !1,
                    random: !1,
                    pause: !1,
                    pauseControls: !0,
                    prevText: "Previous",
                    nextText: "Next",
                    maxwidth: "",
                    navContainer: "",
                    manualControls: "",
                    namespace: "rslides",
                    before: c.noop,
                    after: c.noop
                }, l);
                return this.each(function() {
                    B++;
                    var f = c(this),
                        s, r, t, m, p, q, n = 0,
                        e = f.children(),
                        C = e.size(),
                        h = parseFloat(a.speed),
                        D = parseFloat(a.timeout),
                        u = parseFloat(a.maxwidth),
                        g = a.namespace,
                        d = g + B,
                        E = g + "_nav " + d + "_nav",
                        v = g + "_here",
                        j = d + "_on",
                        w = d + "_s",
                        k = c(""),
                        x = {
                            "float": "left",
                            position: "relative",
                            opacity: 1,
                            zIndex: 2,
                        },
                        y = {
                            "float": "none",
                            position: "absolute",
                            opacity: 0,
                            zIndex: 1
                        },
                        F = function() {
                            var b = (document.body || document.documentElement).style,
                                a = "transition";
                            if ("string" === typeof b[a]) return !0;
                            s = ["Moz", "Webkit", "Khtml", "O", "ms"];
                            var a = a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.substr(1),
                                c;
                            for (c = 0; c "+a+"
                                "});k.append(A);l.navContainer?c(a.navContainer).append(k):f.after(k)}a.manualControls&&(k=c(a.manualControls),k.addClass(g+"
                                _tabs "+d+"
                                _tabs "));(a.pager||a.manualControls)&&k.find("
                                li ").each(function(a){c(this).addClass(w+(a+1))});if(a.pager||a.manualControls)q= k.find("
                                a "),r=function(a){q.closest("
                                li ").removeClass(v).eq(a).addClass(v)};a.auto&&(t=function(){p=setInterval(function(){e.stop(!0,!0);var b=n+1" + a.prevText + "" + a.nextText + ""; l.navContainer ? c(a.navContainer).append(g) : f.after(g);
                                var d = c("." + d + "_nav"), G = d.filter(".prev"); d.bind("click", function(b) {
                                        b.preventDefault();
                                        b = c("." + j);
                                        if (!b.queue("fx").length) {
                                            var d = e.index(b);
                                            b = d - 1;
                                            d = d + 1u && f.css("width", u)
                                        };
                                        H();
                                        c(I).bind("resize", function() {
                                            H()
                                        })
                                    }
                                })
                        }
                })(jQuery, this, 0);
```